# Python: cmd execute last command while prompt and empty line

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-interface

The question may be not clear enough to get.

Let me clear in details. I'm using python cmd library to implement my own CLI framework and when hit the enter button without typing any command it executes last command. This it not one I wanna do.

```
mycli~: cmd --args
executes command
execution stops
mycli~:[hit enter button]
```

Then it will execute again cmd --args. However I just want to go down with new line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a long googling I could not find a valuable advise to prevent this. I decide to go inside the cmd library and override the method.

I figured it out that cmd execute **precmd**, **onecmd** and **postcmd** methods sequentially. I traced the code and see that onecmd is the main one which exetues the given line. It checks parses then check the line. If line is empty it calls the emptyline method and it returns the last command which is a global variable called as **lastcmd**. I override the emptyline method then my issue got fixed.

Here is the method I've written override.

```
def emptyline(self):
        """Called when an empty line is entered in response to the prompt.

        If this method is not overridden, it repeats the last nonempty
        command entered.

        """
        if self.lastcmd:
            return self.onecmd(self.lastcmd)
```

And here is mine:

```
def emptyline(self):
        """Called when an empty line is entered in response to the prompt.

        If this method is not overridden, it repeats the last nonempty
        command entered.

        """
        if self.lastcmd:
            self.lastcmd = ""
            return self.onecmd('\n')
```

It might not be a big deal but keep that in mind just in case.

Comment: Thank you for figuring this out.  I am baffled at the default behavior the cmd module provides for this action.

Comment: Seems that the first answer does the same with less code. Shouldn't it be the answer?

Comment: @rkachach the accepted answer provides more useful details though

Answer (score 21):

```
def emptyline(self):
         pass
```

Will do just fine!

Comment: This issue took me a while to figure out