# Python cmd module enter key

Tags: python, python-cmd

I've built a simple cli app using `cmd`. I noticed that hitting the enter key seems to be rerunning the previous command. Is there a way to catch/prevent this?

Comment: `user_input == ''` or `if not user_input`?

Comment: sorry, dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479029/python-cmd-execute-last-command-while-prompt-and-empty-line. going to close.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.emptyline